# Import Google Maps JS API v3 into Netbeans IDE

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm playing around with the opportunities that google maps give you to make geo tools for your apps, which in wonderful! Just seen the start of how much you can create with the API.

I'm working in Netbeans IDE for PHP. Does anyone know if and how it's possible to somehow import the Google maps API into Netbeans?
The purpose is that when I type something like google. and hit Ctrl+Space, the IDe should show me all the libary opportunities available for google.*
Right now I have to either remember the libary tree, or search for each single libary tree I need. The tool for getting hints in the IDE would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not sure what/how to use it in NetBeans, but the Closure-compiler externs provide all the information you'd need: http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcontrib%2Fexterns%2Fmaps